# Is it possible to chain static together with non-static method in PHP?

Tags: php, static, method-chaining

Here is my sample code Class User but not working when I added the static method with the public methods:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classic;

class User
{
    public $username;
    public static $upassword;
    public $age;
    public $message;

    public function username($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        echo $this->username."<br>";
        return $this;
    }

    public static function password($upassword)
    {
        self::$upassword = $upassword;
        echo self::$upassword."<br>";
    }

    public function age($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        echo $this->age."<br>";
        return $this;
    }

    public function message($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        echo $this->message."<br>";
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and this is the side effect of chaining method:

```
$user = new User();
$user::password('secret')
     ->username('admin')
     ->age(40)
     ->message('lorem ipsum');
```

Comment: Or, you could just stop using static methods and variables. Since they make your code procedural in nature and cause tight coupling to specific class names.

Comment: The static property and method don't have any reason to exist. A static property is common to all instances of the class. **Do you want to use the same password for all users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is the logic behind doing this, but still this solution will be helpful.

[**Try this code  snippet here**](https://eval.in/804973)

```
<?php

namespace App\Classic;

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class User
{

    public $username;
    public static $upassword;
    public static $currentObject=null;//added this variable which hold current class object
    public $age;
    public $message;

    public function __construct()//added a constructor which set's current class object in a static variable
    {
        self::$currentObject= $this;
    }
    public function username($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        echo $this->username . "<br>";
        return $this;//added this statment which will return current class object
    }

    public static function password($upassword)
    {
        self::$upassword = $upassword;
        echo self::$upassword . "<br>";
        return self::$currentObject;
    }

    public function age($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
        echo $this->age . "<br>";
        return $this;
    }

    public function message($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        echo $this->message . "<br>";
        return $this;
    }

}

$user = new User();
$user::password('secret')
        ->username('admin')
        ->age(40)
        ->message('lorem ipsum');
```